# Addressing a shower pan that was not sloped properly

Tags: tile

My tile contractor did not properly slope my shower floor and left a lot of 2"X2" shower floor tiles with numerous lippage spots. I took out all the tile but still have some thinset stuck to the floor.

If I am able to remove all the thinset with out tearing out all the deck mud, do you think it would be alright to just patch and fill areas in the deck mud?

Or should I take out all the deck mud and start all over?

I also had to dig down to the vinyl liner around the drain because my tile contractor installed the vinyl liner over the drain flange and the locking coupling.  I was able to remove the locking coupling and install it over the vinyl liner. I think I can back fill this area with gravel and deck mud, but not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: "*If I am able to remove all the thinset with out tearing out all the deck mud, do you think it would be alright to just patch and fill areas in the deck mud?*"  That does not address the fact that the pan does not have the proper slope.  Perhaps When you say properly sloped   you mean   **not flat**.  Is it sloped so water flows to the drain?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you practically have all the concrete removed. It may be wise to bite the bullet and start anew. For the sake of consistency it's better to have a floor pan from one single installation.

It certainly is possible to install patched areas in concrete and have them function as expected. Shallow chisel divots can be filled and if the area is solid without cracks and hasn't been jolted-loose from the demolition the odds are good for a repair.

Comment: I agree with having a solid pan or later when someone rocks back on a heel (small contact area with full weight)  the bottom breaks. If there was a solid structure below this I would say ok but gravel, no it needs to be redone with the correct slope to start with.

Comment: I agree with this, so won't bother with a separate answer. I'll add, though, that the materials at this stage (deck mud/sand mix) are cheap compared to everything else in the shower. If you have to have a do-over, this is the place you want to have it. Also, unless you are the "tile contractor," you should never let that tile contractor in your house again.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice.  Looks like I will replace all the deck mud.  Will give it try by myself. Tough to find a reasonable tile contractor.